# How to lock the image at center in cover flow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coverflow

I am using the open flow library in my project.What I have to do is when the user double tap the image it should go to aniother view controller.It is going well but the problem is when I am implementing this the image is not locking at center.
code where the problem is:-

```
    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        NSSet *allTouches=[event allTouches];
        UITouch *touch=[[allTouches allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
        int intval=[touch tapCount];

        if (intval==1) {
    nslog(@"one tap");
[self singletapMethod];
    }
    else if(intval==2)
    {
    nslog(@"double tap");
[self doubletapMethod];
    }

}
```